# Using CAT command read all file content recursively for paths file

Tags: linux, string, shell, cat

So I've a file called `allTextFiles.txt` in which it has paths of a all regular text file.

eg:
./test/file1.txt
./test/file2.txt
./test/file3.txt

My task is to formulate shell command such that command CAT will go through all of these paths and display content of each file.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

**Using xargs with the allTextFiles.txt**

You can use the command cat to list the content and xargs [(Xargs command documentation)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to process every line of the file. For example:

```
cat allTextFiles.txt | xargs cat
kk #./test/file1.txt
jj #./test/file2.txt
yy #./test/file3.txt
```

**Using find command without allTextFiles.txt**

You can use the command `find` [(find command documentation)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to go trough the main folder and search recursively. Once you find a file, to use the cat command.

You achieve the purpose of showing all the content of txt files recursively with only one command.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} \;
kk #./test/file1.txt
jj #./test/file2.txt
yy #./test/file3.txt
```

Where the `.` means current directory. `-type f` only filters files. `-name "*.txt"` filters only files ending with .txt extension and the `-exec` part is where you process all the files found.

Does it cover your need?

Comment: Thanks the xargs command worked well. My next task is to use grep command to look for specific keyword and if it matched then display filename. I tried with option -l (ell) but in output I'm getting weird text like `<stdin>`.
This was my command
`cat allTextFiles.txt | xargs cat | grep -l "flag"`
Can you please help me here ?

Comment: Then use xargs grep command. `cat allTextFiles.txt | xargs grep -l kk` where the output in this case will be: `./test1/file.txt`. Just the name of the file it matched.

Comment: No, I mean the overall task is to look for a keyword `flag` in specified text files and whichever the file matches the pattern output that exact file path.

Comment: You mean to print the content of all the file only if it matches the keyword flag? `cat allTextFiles.txt | xargs grep -l kk | xargs cat`

Comment: Not the content of file but only the file path if the keyword `flag` is found in the content of file.

Comment: But this is what `cat allTextFiles.txt | xargs grep -l kk` is doing. If the file contains the flag string, it will list the name of this file. In this case, it only shows `./test1/file.txt` because it contains your string.

Answer (score 1):

try this will work

cat Folder/*.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop; something like

```sh
while IFS= read -r file; do
    cat "$file"
done < allTextFiles.txt
```

See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more discussion on reading a file a line at a time (Much of the content applies to all shells, not just bash).

If you *are* using bash:

```sh
readarray -t files < allTextFiles.txt
cat "${files[@]}"
```

is an alternative that avoids the explicit loop.

Comment: Why would you use `-r` here?  If the input file contains a string like `foo\ bar`, or a line that ends in \, you would expect those escapes to be honored.  If you use `-r`, there is no way for the script to escape characters.  I'm not a big fan of using whitespace in filenames, but it happens, and `-r` just makes it more difficult to deal with.

Comment: Why would you *not* use `-r`? I wouldn't expect escapes in a filename in a text file unless it's source code.

Comment: This is literally the first time in 20+ years I've seen someone suggest leaving it off a `read`.

Comment: `-r` limits your flexibility.  In particular, there are too many situations in which it is not possible to shorten lines with escape sequences, and arbitrarily denying the use of escapes seems unnecessary.  You don't lose any functionality by reading without -r, and any perceived benefit of simplicity is often offset by added confusion.  In any case, it is clearly situationally dependent, but I dislike the arbitrary application of `-r` without reason.  It is often touted as best-practice, but it really shouldn't be.